# Storing hexadecimal addresses, misunderstanding DWORD_PTR

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a program to write a value to a multi level pointer found with certain offsets. The function I will show needs to return the correct address. Assume I have all the datatypes of the variables outside of the function matching up.

```
DWORD FindDmaAddy(int PointerLevel, HANDLE HProcHandle, DWORD Offsets[], DWORD BaseAddress) 
{
    DWORD Pointer = BaseAddress;
    DWORD pTemp = NULL;
    DWORD PointerAddR;
    for (int i = 0; i < PointerLevel; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            ReadProcessMemory(HProcHandle, (LPCVOID)Pointer, &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), NULL); 
            std::cout << pTemp<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "pTemp = " << pTemp << std::endl;
        PointerAddR = pTemp + Offsets[i];
        std::cout << "PointerAddR = " <<PointerAddR << std::endl;
        std::cout << "i = " << i<<std::endl;

        ReadProcessMemory(HProcHandle, (LPCVOID)PointerAddR, &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), NULL); 
    }
    return PointerAddR;
```

This code worked fine when the function was called, and the correct address changed value (there is a write function somewhere else), only it came up with two of the same warning beforehand.

```
Warning C4312   'type cast': conversion from 'DWORD' to 'LPCVOID' of greater size
```

I figured this would be fixed if I changed relevant variables to DWORD_PTR, so I changed it to this.

```
DWORD_PTR FindDmaAddy(int PointerLevel, HANDLE HProcHandle, DWORD_PTR Offsets[], DWORD_PTR BaseAddress) 
{
    DWORD_PTR Pointer = BaseAddress;
    DWORD_PTR pTemp = NULL;
    DWORD_PTR PointerAddR;
    for (int i = 0; i < PointerLevel; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            ReadProcessMemory(HProcHandle, (LPCVOID)Pointer, &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), NULL); 
        }
        std::cout << "pTemp = " << pTemp << std::endl;
        PointerAddR = pTemp + Offsets[i];
        std::cout << "PointerAddR = " <<PointerAddR << std::endl;
        std::cout << "i = " << i<<std::endl;

        ReadProcessMemory(HProcHandle, (LPCVOID)PointerAddR, &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), NULL); 
    }
return PointerAddR;
```

But when I use this code, it doesn't work. I checked the output of the original and the changed one, and it goes from this:

```
pTemp = 44803720
PointerAddR = 44804620
i = 0
pTemp = 44767240
PointerAddR = 44767260
i = 1
pTemp = 44804056
PointerAddR = 44804056
i = 2
```

To This:

```
44803720
pTemp = 44803720
PointerAddR = 44804620
i = 0
pTemp = 34605865808631816
PointerAddR = 34605865808631836
i = 1
pTemp = 34605865808631816
PointerAddR = 34605865808631816
i = 2
```

What gives? ReadProcessMemory works fine on the first run, and on the second run it stores the address in this weird form. But it's reading the exact same data types and being called the exact same way.

Comment: When you changed to DWORD_PTR, that also changed sizeof(pTemp), so you are passing different parameters now

Comment: Agh. That makes more sense. But why doesn't this affect the first ReadProcessMemory? When it prints pTemp, it's still printing something sizeof(pTemp), but the second time it stores a completely different address, even though a DWORD_PTR address is being read and stored into a DWORD_PTR variable. EDIT: Also if you don't think that was a good way to handle the warnings let me know.

Comment: What is the bitness (32/64) of your process and the target process?

Comment: 64bit code getting a handle from a 32 bit window, but it was my understanding DWORD_PTR was compatible across bits. And I'm still a bit confused why the first ReadProcessMemory can be sizeof(dword) or sizeof(dword_ptr) but the second one is more rigid.

Comment: Wow I'm stupid. ReadProcessMemory works fine on the first run because the bytes after the first address were 0x00000000. So when it ran the second time at the new address it read all these irrelevant bytes. It works when compiled for 32 bit and when the 4th parameter for both readprocessmemory's is sizeof(dword).

Comment: `DWORD_PTR` is an unsigned value the same size as a pointer. So in a 64 bit process it's 8 bytes and in a 32 bit process it's 4 bytes. If you're reading pointer-sized data from a 32 bit process you need to only read 4 bytes even if your process is 64 bit.

Comment: If you are a 64-bit app reading from a 32-bit app, then you need 32-bit values to represent "pointers in that 32-bit app over there". So they should stay `DWORD`. You can avoid the compiler warning by doing an intermediate conversion: `(LPCVOID)(DWORD_PTR)myDwordVariable`.

Answer (score 0):

In 32/64-bit programs, `sizeof(DWORD) = 4;`
In 32-bit `sizeof(DWORD_PTR) = 4` but in 64-bit, the value is 8;
the first value reading from `pTemp` in memory(8 bytes) is `88A6AB0200000000`, So according to byte order rules, the value is `0x0000000002ABA688`(44803720), and the second one in 8 byte is `0818AB02DAF17A`, value = 34605865808631816, If you read only the previous 4 bytes, it is 44767240, which is the same result as your result in 32-bit. 64-bit process will not change the memory of pointer in 32-bit in another process. So you should read the process memory as the bit of target process here.

Answer (score 0):

As Drake said the pointer size is the problem, 4 bytes vs 8 bytes.

Since you posted this we have changed our FindDMAAddy to be cleaner and now it looks like this

```cpp
uintptr_t FindDMAAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)ptr, &ptr, sizeof(ptr), 0);
        ptr += offsets[i];
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Few lines of code, no need for defining the length manually and x64 compatible as long as your build type matches the architecture of the target process.  So if your target process is x86 compile for x86.  Using uintptr_t is similar to DWORD_PTR as it's definition changes based on build type to fit the size of a pointer.

That should solve your problem.